# Concatenating my entire app into just an HTML, JS and CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, gruntjs

I built an AngularJS app that has a structure something like this:

```
theprojectroot
|- src
|     |- app
|     |     |- index.html
|     |     |- index.js
|     |     |- userhome
|     |     |     |- userhome.html
|     |     |     |- userhome.js
|     |     |- management
|     |     |     |- management.html
|     |     |     |- management.js
|     |     |- social
|     |     |     |- social.html
|     |     |     |- social.js
|     |- assets
|- vendor
|- package.json
```

Obviously, there are more directories and js files to it, but the idea is that I have each component of the app in a different directory, including its HTML page (which is loaded into `index.html` using `ui-router`) and it's JS file, containing its Angular module, controllers, etc.

I want to put my app into production and I remember reading somewhere that this can and should be done such that the end result is just three files.

- theproject.html
- theproject.js
- theproject.css

I've been doing some research and Googling for such a solution, preferably using Grunt. However, I have not found any instructions on how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the direction or provide instructions on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a grunt task to concat all the files automatically
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-css

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Just some examples but it might save you some time from copy pasta

Answer (score -2):

I don't know wether there is a software solution, but it is possible without.

- Simplest thing are the .css files, just copy them together. You can't do it if you need to include special .css for i.e. IE, but most should fit in one (or two) requests. Copy them together in the same order you'd load them to not break any overwritten content. If you want to reduce network latency even more, inline it.
- JS is a little more difficult. One file may be bad since you shouldn't modify the default angular script, but putting all of your code in one file should work. Be sure to concatenate any onLoad-functions. You could try pasting it below the angular code, but better test it beforehand. Again, you may inline your code.
- The probably most network intensive but also most difficult files are the html files.

  - If you need to do some preprocessing on the server side, you're out of luck. Try to export it into an API.
  - If it's static html, you have 2 options. The first one is to fetch all of the HTML in one (embedded) json file and then load it 'from ram'. The better way would be to embedd all the code in your `theproject.html` and hide it until you 'load' that page. This would probably be the most performant way.

Some other tips if you need raw load speed:

- minify and compress your html, js and css files.
- activate gzip
- load the data you don't need to render on your index page with a second request, so that the browser doesn't have to wait until all of this is fetched. This will greatly improve the time for the first page render if your application is big. Inline your controller and the part of the css that is required for you index page, fetch the rest afterwards. Your page could be rendered after two network requests.

Comment: Your solution is that I do all that work manually? That isn't ideal

Comment: Should not be impossible to write some simple Perl scripts for this, Everything except scanning JS onLoad's and edit the html loading (which can be done in too many ways to get them all) can be done quickly. Also, I pointed out how to do it, I don't know wether there is a program to do it, but I don't think there is because of above problem[s]. Should be easy to do for your specific project however.